# VBA Excel Sub continues running after Form was unloaded

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know what happened but after I implemented a new code the 'Sub' continues running after I press my 'Cancel' button.

My 'Cancel' Button:

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()

If Cancel Then Exit Sub
Cancel = True

'Save Settings
....

Unload Me
End Sub
```

My Sub and new function:

```
Sub Example()
  Dim myArr() as string
  ...
  some loops....
     If Cancel Then
        Exit Sub
     End If
     myArr = NewFunction(a1,a2)
     myVar = myArr(1)
  ...
End Sub

Function NewFunction(a1,a2) As String ()
    Dim tmpArr() as string
    ...
    ReDim tmpArr(1)
    ...
    NewFunction = tmpArr()
 End Function
```

Issues:

1. If I avoid execution of line `myVar = myArr(1)` the code continues running after canceling, so I need to stop execution manually. Why?
2. If line `myVar = myArr(1)` is executed, the form will be unloaded and error appears:

> runtime error 9
>
> Subscript out of range

Don't get it what is wrong. The code runs ok if I'm not canceling it. The problem only is with 'Cancel' button which was working perfect before...

Cheers, Andy

Form buttons:
[image: Picture1]

Comment: Would you upload a pic of your form.

Comment: What is the variable "Cancel"? Where is it Dim'ed?

Comment: @Masoud Added...

Comment: @Rich Holton 'Cancel' is a global 'boolean', I updated main code from above sub which checks in each loop if 'cancel' is true. However 'Cancel' is not initiated anywhere as 'true' at this moment.

Comment: That could be part of your problem. Make sure you initialize it to true as part of initialization. Doesn't explain the runtime error, though.

Comment: @Rich Holton, sorry, Cancel is initialized as 'false' in UserForm_Initialize().

Comment: You seem to be saying that you set a boolean `Cancel` variable in one sub and expect other subs to see it and stop. There is no multi-threading in VBA. Please explain concisely the sequence of events/operations that is happening. i.e. when is the cancel button clicked, when are the other functions invoked and how, etc.

Comment: I will try to remove 'Cancel' variable. The idea is that I'm opening files for reading in Sub's loops. I need to make sure to 'close' opened file when I'm  canceling form. However I have and I need 2 bools to be passed between subs and functions.

Comment: @Andy Yeah, I meant to say False instead of True. Thanks for the graceful correction.

Comment: HAHA... Worked! Fixed one more bug :)

Comment: One more question, if 'Form' is unloaded, will be opened file from Sub closed automatically? I mean, it should be used 'Close #f' or something?

Comment: @Andy You need to define `Cancel` as true and set it to false when user click RunApp. Your cancel button should just hide/unload the userform. Of course cancel needs to be a Public which is defined outside of your main module. That would work.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct code which works for me:

```
Dim Cancel As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Cancel = False
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    SetStatus ("Cancelling")

    If Cancel = False Then
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Save Settings
    '... some code

    If Cancel Then
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
Sub Example()
   '...
   'some loops....
   If Cancel Then
       'close open files...
       '... some code
       SetStatus ("Cancelled")
       Exit Sub
   End If
   '...
End Sub
```

When 'Cancel' button is pressed, the code will stop in safe manner.  Then the second click on 'Cancel' button the form will be unloaded.